# FusedLocationApi method getLastLocation() always null during first call

Tags: java, android, location, android-gps

Looking for some help with a problem in my app concerning getting the current device location. Below is the GPSLocationListener class I am using.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;



/**
 * This class takes care of capturing the location of the device.
 */
public class GPSLocationListener implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {


    protected static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";

    public static final int LOCATION_RESQUEST = 1;
    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    private Activity mActivity;

    public double lat;
    public double lon;

    public GPSLocationListener(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        // Kick off the process of building a GoogleApiClient and requesting the LocationServices API.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
     * LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Navigation Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    public void startLocationUpdates(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //return;
            }else {
                try {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                            LOCATION_RESQUEST);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // If the initial location was never previously requested, we use
            // FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() to get it. If it was previously requested, we store
            // its value in the Bundle and check for it in onCreate().
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        //createLocationRequest();
        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.

    }

    public void onStop() {
        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.mActivity, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onConnected: Just empty if statement");
            }else {
                try {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                            LOCATION_RESQUEST);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
                mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                Log.i(TAG, "onConnected  " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback that fires when the location changes.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_RESQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    startLocationUpdates(); // Calling this here is the only place that does not make the app crash
                    getCurrentLocation();
                }else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: Need Permissions");
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return;
    }

    public void getCurrentLocation(){
        if (mCurrentLocation != null){
            lat = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            lon = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            Log.i(TAG, "getCurrentLocation(): " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            Log.i(TAG, "getCurrentLocation(): " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(){
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

}
```

Trying this out on my actual device with the GPS already enabled in the settings, I get some odd behavior. If I do not at all, call the `startLocationUpdates()` method or I call it in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method, the app launches fine and when I grant Device Location Permissions, the `mCurrentLocation` object is null, but does not crash. I stop the app and then launch again, and the `mCurrentLocation` has latitude and longitude coordinates that I can see in the logcat, which is what I am wanting in the first place, but they only hold any values, after the second launch. Now if I uninstall the app and try to call the `startLocationUpdates()` method anywhere, the app crashes upon launch with the error:

```
Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
```

But I am checking for permissions in the `onConnected()` method and also in the `startLocationUpdates()` method as well, although I do not think this is correct but this is the only way that I can get Android Studio to not underline the

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

statement in red with a Permissions warning.

Here is the `Activity` where I am trying to get the location updates with the `mapItBtnRespond()` method.

```
package com.example.bigdaddy.as_built_weldmapper;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bigdaddy.as_built_weldmapper.utilities.BendHelper;
import com.example.bigdaddy.as_built_weldmapper.utilities.GPSLocationListener;

public class SagActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,
        MajorButtonFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Communicator{

    /* Using this to insert into the Bend Direction field. */
    public static String SAG_DIRECTION = "SAG";

    /* This spinner holds the bend types */
    Spinner mSagBendTypesSpinner;

    /* Using this string to collect what was selected for the spinner type */
    private String mBendTypeSpinnerVal;

    /* All the EditText for the Activity */
    private EditText mSagGpsShotEt;
    private EditText mSagExistingGpsEt;
    private EditText mSagCoverEt;
    private EditText mSagDegreeEt;
    private EditText mSagDistanceFromEt;
    private EditText mSagNotesEt;
    private EditText mSagOccupyIdEt;
    private EditText mSagStationNumEt;

    private GPSLocationListener mGPSLocationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sag);

        mGPSLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener(SagActivity.this);

        /* checking if the MajorButtonFragment is null */
        if (findViewById(R.id.majorButtonFragment) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
        }

        /* Referencing the spinner and setting the itemsSelectedListener */
        mSagBendTypesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bend_types_spinner);
        mSagBendTypesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        /* Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout */
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.bend_types_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        /* Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears */
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        /* Apply the adapter to the spinner */
        mSagBendTypesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        /* Referencing and calling all the EditText for the Activity */
        mSagGpsShotEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextGpsShotForSag);
        mSagExistingGpsEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextExistGradeForSag);
        mSagCoverEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextCoverForSag);
        mSagDegreeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextDegreeForSag);
        mSagDistanceFromEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextDistanceFromForSag);
        mSagNotesEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextNotesForSagActivity);
        mSagOccupyIdEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextJointIdSagActivity);
        mSagStationNumEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTextStationNumSagActivity);
    } /*onCreate() ends here.*/

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("SagActivity", "onStart: ");
        /* Starting the location listener here (GoogleApiClient) */
        if (mGPSLocationListener != null){
            mGPSLocationListener.onStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("SagActivity", "onStop: ");
        /* Stopping the location listener here (GoogleApiClient) */
        if (mGPSLocationListener != null){
            mGPSLocationListener.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocalVoiceInteractionStopped() {
        super.onLocalVoiceInteractionStopped();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        mBendTypeSpinnerVal = mSagBendTypesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void exitBtnRespond() {

    }

    /**
     * This overridden method comes from the Communicator Interface and is used globally in all
     * Activities that implement it to Store (write) a transaction to the database.
     * The utility class saveAndInsertBend() method is invoked here.
     */
    @Override
    public void storeBtnRespond() {
        BendHelper.saveAndInsertBend(SagActivity.this, SAG_DIRECTION, mBendTypeSpinnerVal, mSagStationNumEt,
                mSagOccupyIdEt, mSagDegreeEt, mSagDistanceFromEt, mSagGpsShotEt, mSagExistingGpsEt,
                mSagCoverEt, mSagNotesEt);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapItBtnRespond() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MapItBtn clicked in SagActivity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mGPSLocationListener.getCurrentLocation();
        Log.i("SagActivity", "mapItBtnRespond: " + String.valueOf(mGPSLocationListener.lat));
        Log.i("SagActivity", "mapItBtnRespond: " + String.valueOf(mGPSLocationListener.lon));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction() {

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here with all of this? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am confused with the Permissions apparently. Thanks so much for any guidance.

Comment: Why don't you ask permission when the getCurrentLocation() method is called in SagActivity ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam. I have thought of that also but I plan on using the GPS helper class across multiple activities and hoped to take care of the Permissions request once and for all within that class instead of each Activity individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for FINE_LOCATION permission in onConnected(), but onConnected is called when GPS is connected. That's the reason you are getting permission error.

You should remove this:

```
mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

From onConnected(). Add this to getCurrentLocation() with permission request:

```
public void getCurrentLocation(){
        //Request permission here
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mCurrentLocation != null){
            lat = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            lon = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            Log.i(TAG, "getCurrentLocation(): " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            Log.i(TAG, "getCurrentLocation(): " + String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
```

Then also call this method in onConnected():

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
            getCurrentLocation();
    }
```